# ActiveMQ remote connections refused despite 0.0.0.0 in broker URL

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I have an ActiveMQ v5.7.0 broker, running in Karaf v2.3.3, that I want to enable for remote connections.  I've set the broker URL to 0.0.0.0:61616, to enable it to listen to network traffic.  I've opened the firewall to allow the traffic from the client machines.  However, all remote connections are being refused.  A quick netstat seems to tell me that the broker isn't listening outside of localhost.

```
jeremy@server:~$ netstat -pan | grep 61616
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:61616         :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Looking at the broker via [Hawtio](http://hawt.io/) tells me that the URL looks as it should.

```
Transport connectors    Openwire: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600
```

The firewall is definitely OK, as the connections are being refused rather than just being dropped.

The broker is responding correctly to connections from localhost.

```
2013-10-14 17:34:29 Connected to localhost:61613
```

This is the sort of error I get from remote connections:-

```
Error connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61613: IO::Socket::INET: connect: Connection refused at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Net/Stomp.pm line 102.
```

**EDIT**: telnet output added

Localhost port 61613

```
jeremy@server:~$ telnet localhost 61613
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Remote connection port 61613

```
jeremy@other-server:~$ telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 61613
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Localhost connection port 61616 (this one is interesting)

```
jeremy@server:~$ telnet localhost 61616
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
ðActiveMQ       Þ
MaxFrameSizÿÿÿ  CacheSize
CacheEnabledSizePrefixDisabled MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay'TcpNoDelayEnabledMaxInactivityDurationu0TightEncodingEnabledStackTraceEnabledPuTTYConnection closed by foreign host.
```

Remote connection port 61616

```
jeremy@other-server:~$ telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 61616
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

**EDIT**: remote server karaf log output added

```
2013-10-15 19:00:46,599 | ERROR | c.event.invited] | faultJmsMessageListenerContainer | .DefaultMessageListenerContainer  909 | 69 - org.springframework.jms - 3.2.4.RELEASE | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'Consumer.notifications.VirtualTopic.event.invited' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Here's the broker.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">

  <ext:property-placeholder />

  <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    brokerName="jellyfish-messaging"
    dataDirectory="${karaf.data}/activemq/localhost"
    useShutdownHook="false"
    persistent="true"
    schedulerSupport="true"
    startAsync="true">

    <destinationPolicy>
      <policyMap>
        <policyEntries>
          <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
            <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
              <vmCursor />
            </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
          </policyEntry>
          <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
          </policyEntry>
        </policyEntries>
      </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy> 

    <persistenceAdapter>
      <kahaDB directory="${karaf.data}/activemq/localhost/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>

    <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="64 mb"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <!-- The transport connectors ActiveMQ will listen to -->
    <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>

  </broker>

  <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <property name="maximumActive" value="500" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="resourceManager" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.ActiveMQResourceManager" init-method="recoverResource">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="resourceName" value="activemq.localhost" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transacted" value="false" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
  </bean>

  <reference id="transactionManager" interface="javax.transaction.TransactionManager" />

  <service ref="pooledConnectionFactory" interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
    <service-properties>
      <entry key="name" value="localhost"/>
    </service-properties>
  </service>
</blueprint>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks,

J.

Comment: Can you please try telnetting in to both 61613 and 61616 from a local and remote host and add the output to the question?

Comment: This all looks OK from an ActiveMQ config standpoint. It definitely feels like a firewall issue - if you're on a Linux machine you may have a local one such as iptables running. Telnetting in to JMX (1099) should confirm it - there's nothing in any config that blocks it off from remote boxes.

Comment: Thanks - I've gone back over it and it really doesn't seem like a firewall issue.  The netstat output (at the top of my post) indicates to me that ActiveMQ is not listening outside of localhost.  I tried to telnet from the ActiveMQ server to its own IP address, with the firewall disabled, and I still get "Connection Refused".
`jeremy@server:~$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
jeremy@server:~$ telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 61616
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
jeremy@server:~$ sudo ufw enable`

Comment: Just an extra thought - could someone share a working example broker.xml that accepts external traffic?  Just in case there is something otherwise glaringly obviously wrong with mine.

Comment: The default `conf/activemq.xml` accepts external traffic.

Comment: Thanks again - I'll deploy a copy of it onto the troublesome machine and see how it looks in netstat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this.  It was neither a problem with the firewall, nor with the ActiveMQ configuration.

The Karaf kar file in which the ActiveMQ broker was defined included the *activemq-web-console* feature.  We've not been using this feature, as we're fans of Hawtio, so had never configured it.

As per [this blog post](http://marcelojabali.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/how-to-enable-activemq-web-console-on.html), the console was coming up with default settings, including listening on port 61616.  This meant that two brokers were in a race condition on start-up and the webconsole-defined one was generally winning.  Since by default it isn't configured for remote access, it was locking the port for localhost connections only.

The giveaway was a directory called *${activemq.data}* (literally) within the Karaf home directory, containing a second Kahadb repository.  All of our broker config was set to use the *data* directory and we've never specifically set the ActiveMQ environment variables, so this led us to look for where a second broker might have come from.

Might have spotted it more quickly had we done *activemq:list* inside a Karaf session, as it was listing two brokers.

Simple solution - delete *activemq-web-console* from the features XML.